# c# linq left join

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I want to perform left join that will work like its working in sql server/mysql.

for example : 
mysql:
table a
        LEFT outer JOIN
    tableb  ON b.AId = a.bId

linq :

```
  from b in ctx.tableb.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I thought maybe to add this in the condition:

```
  b.Aid = a.bId
```

But then it return me result like normal inner join.

If try without it then in the result i get all rows from table b with the result of a (duplicate results ).

I want it to return the rows from table A like regular left join:

"The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match"

There is a way the query will act like in mysql ?

If i'm doing distinct the problem solved but i don't think that this is the way..

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**How to perform Left Outer Join with LINQ**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) you can make your query look like:

```
from b in ctx.tableb                                 
join a in ctx.tablea on b equals tablea.b into ba
from c in ba.DefaultIfEmpty()
select { [ResultFromTableb] = b.[ColumnNameInTableb],..., [ResultFromTablea] = ba = null ? string.Empty : a.[ColumnNameInTablea] }
```

Note, that if you do use select like

```
select ba;
```

, and later reference a column from a selection row, you will get `NullReferenceException` for any row from `ba` that is null(and you get a null row, if you have even a  single null column in it).

Comment: @aNerd

Hi, its working now, thanks.
but this is the best performance?

I can do something like this too and its working :

**bold** from c in (from l in table b where b.Aid equals a.bId select l).DefaultIfEmpty()**bold**

Comment: Can you post the exact code because this doesn't seem a valid linq-2-entities query?

Comment: something like this :
`from b in ctx.tableb                                 
from c in (from l in ctx.tablea on b equals tablea.b select l).DefaultIfEmpty()
select { [ResultFromTableb] = b.[ColumnNameInTableb],..., [ResultFromTablea] = ba = null ? string.Empty : a.[ColumnNameInTablea] }`

Comment: If you mean query without join, for example
"from b in ctx.tableb
from a in ctx.tablea.DefaultIfEmpty()" 
this.is more like cross join and returns every row from b with every row from a.
If you add "where b.Aid == a.bId" you get inner join with only results which don't contain nullable columns like the left join.
You can not use on without join in linq.
If you have working code. please post it as it is because the code from the comments is not exactly working.

Comment: i'm having trouble imagining how to properly extend this when you have several joins (possibly left joins) and you need the result to contain fields from all the joined tables.

Answer (score -1):

from a in tableA join b in tableB on a equals b.Owner into gj  from c in gj.DefaultIfEmpty() select new { a.FirstName, PetName = (c== null ? String.Empty : c.Name) };